# How do i generate random value for my test requests in SOAPUI?

Tags: rest, get, automated-tests, soapui

I have a series of test steps in my SOAPUI test suite, I want to generate a random value and pass it to the tests?. I've tried to use ${=(int)(Math.random()*50000)} but it only passes different random values to my tests requests.

Thank you

Comment: Where do you want the random number if you don't wish to the test requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to pass the same random value to all Test Steps in a given Test Suite.

1. Create a Setup Script, it's located at the bottom of your Testsuite window:

`runner.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "rnd",((int)Math.random()*50000).toString());`

2. Use the newly created Property in your Teststeps:

`=${#TestSuite#rnd}`

Now whenever you run your Testsuite another random value will be created and all Teststeps in all Testcases use the same value.